# Use select_related in Django 1.7

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have this structure

- Group 1

  - Group 2

    - Group 3

I want to print all groups. Right now I am doing this in the templates as

```
<ul>
{% for group1 in group1_list %}
    <li>{{ group1 }}</li>
    <ul>
        {% for group2 in group1.group2_set.all %}
            <li>{{ group2 }}</li>
            <ul>
                {% for group3 in group2.group3_set.all %}
                    <li>{{ group3 }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

but it takes up alot of memory with all the database calls, so I was wondering if I could do the same with `select_related`.

I could use `Group3.objects.all().select_related('group2','group2__group1')` and print the objects as I want with the `{% regroup %}` tag.

The problem arises when a group 2 object does not have any related group 3 objects. Is it possible to walk from all the group 1 objects and select all children of the group 1 and group 2 objects?

Comment: I don't understand why you've specified "Django 1.7" in the question, as this appears to have nothing specific to that version.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) does.

Comment: What would it be?

`Group1.objects.all().prefetch_related('group2_set', 'group2_set__group3_set')` or what?